# UICollectionView's FlowLayout wrapping is no working as expected (IOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to build photo gallery as a practice to learn IOS. The requirement was to get random images and make sure there're at least 2-images per row. I tried UICollectionView but it's not working as expected! Am I missing something?

Here's a link for the [github repository](https://github.com/AhmedFat7y/photo-gallery-ios)

I'm calling the photosvie in *ViewController.m* like this

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self presentViewController:[[PhotosGridView alloc] init] animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

then the *init* method in *PhotosGridView.m*

```
-(PhotosGridView *)init {
    NSLog(@"initalizin photos grid view");
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *aFlowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [aFlowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(150, 140)];
    [aFlowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
    return [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:aFlowLayout];
}
```

To register the custom cell class I use this (recommended by a friend) in *viewDidLoad* method:

```
UINib *nibForTheCell = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"PhotosGridViewCell" bundle:nil];
[self.collectionView registerNib:nibForTheCell forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

Then for binding each cell I use these methods in same file

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PhotosGridViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"im in loading cell %li", (long)indexPath.row);
    // Configure the cell
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self generateURLString]];
    [[cell imageView] sd_setImageWithURL:(baseURL) completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        CGSize size = [self decideSize: image];
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, size.width, size.height);
        cell.imageView.hidden = false;
        cell.activityIndicator.hidden = true;
//        NSLog(@"\nImageSize: (%f, %f)", image.size.width, image.size.height);
//        NSLog(@"\nCellSize: (%f, %f)", size.width, size.height);
    }];
    return cell;
}

-(NSString *) generateURLString {
    int width = 250 + arc4random_uniform(600);
    int height = 300 + arc4random_uniform(600);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://lorempixel.com/%i/%i/", width, height];
}

-(CGSize) decideSize: (UIImage *)image {
    CGSize s;
    int minWidth = (self.view.frame.size.width - 200) / 2;
    s.width = MIN(minWidth, image.size.width);
    if (s.width != image.size.width) {
        s.height = (image.size.height * s.width) / image.size.width;
    }
    return s;

}
```

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYPK6.png) for how it looks like now

[image: screenshot]